# How do I convert unicode characters to floats in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, floating-point

I am parsing a webpage which has Unicode representations of fractions.  I would like to be able to take those strings directly and convert them to floats.  For example:

"⅕" would become 0.2

Any suggestions of how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to use the [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) module:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.numeric(u'⅕')
```

This will print:

```
0.20000000000000001
```

If the character does not have a numeric value, then `unicodedata.numeric(unichr[, default])` will return default, or if default is not given will raise ValueError.

Comment: Python should get a new slogan by borrowing from Apple: "There's a module for that".

Comment: I didn't realize it until I just read the docs that ftp.unicode.org has a UnicodeData.txt file which is where the unicodedata module is getting all its data from.

Comment: I had no idea that you could do that!

Comment: Neither did I - that's truly amazing

Comment: For the morbidly curious it seems the python implementation of numeric is basically just a big lookup table, see python/trunk/Objects/unicodectype.c

Also, there are obviously a lot more unicode characters with numeric values than just the standard fractions ... check out http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0f2e/index.htm for example!

Answer (score 6):

Those Unicode representations of floats are called [Vulgar Fractions](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Decomposition_Type=Fraction:])

You can covert them to floats using [unicodedata.numeric(char)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.numeric)

However, `numeric(char)` won't work on something like `3¾`. That takes a bit more effort:

```
from unicodedata import numeric

samples = ["3¼","19¼","3 ¼","10"]

for i in samples:
    if len(i) == 1:
        v = numeric(i)
    elif i[-1].isdigit():
        # normal number, ending in [0-9]
        v = float(i)
    else:
        # Assume the last character is a vulgar fraction
        v = float(i[:-1]) + numeric(i[-1])
    print(i, v)
```

Output:

```
3¼ 3.25
19¼ 19.25
3 ¼ 3.25
10 10.0
```

You might also be interested isolating these vulgar fractions from broader user input using regular expressions. You can do so using ranges of their unicode character codes:

```
/[\u2150-\u215E\u00BC-\u00BE]/g
```

Sample: https://regexr.com/3p8nd

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only a fixed number of fractions defined in Unicode, a dictionary seems appropriate:

```
Fractions = {
    u'¼': 0.25,
    u'½': 0.5,
    u'¾': 0.75,
    u'⅕': 0.2,
    # add any other fractions here
}
```

Update: the `unicodedata` module is a much better solution.

Comment: Specifically, you're looking at characters U+00BC-E
(http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) and U+2153-E (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2150.pdf). Just search the index (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Index.txt) for "vulgar".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could decompose the fraction using the ["unicodedata" module](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) and then look for the [FRACTION SLASH character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm) and then it's just a matter of simple division.

For example:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.lookup('VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER')
u'\xbc'
>>> unicodedata.decomposition(unicodedata.lookup('VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER'))
'<fraction> 0031 2044 0034'
```

**Update:** I'll leave this answer here for reference but using unicodedata.numeric() as per Karl's answer is a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.1, you don't need the 'u', and it will produce 0.2 instead of 0.20000000000000001
.

```
>>> unicodedata.numeric('⅕')
0.2
```

Comment: assert (0.2 == 0.20000000000000001) ... What you possibly meant to say is that the float produced by the unicodedata.numeric() has NOT changed, but repr() has been enhanced to produce a less frightening but still computationally equivalent answer where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stating the obvious here, but it's very simple to extend this for cases when people write "1¾" meaning "1.75", so I'm just going to share it here for quick reference:

```
import unicodedata

# Assuming that the unicode is always the last character. You always going to see stuff like "3¼", or "19¼" whereas stuff like "3¼5"
# does not have a clear interpretation 

def convertVulgarFractions(vulgarFraction):

    if (len(vulgarFraction) == 1):
        return unicodedata.numeric(vulgarFraction)

    if (len(vulgarFraction) > 1) & (not (vulgarFraction[:len(vulgarFraction)-1].isdigit())):
        raise ArithmeticError("The format needs to be numbers ending with a vulgar fraction. The number inserted was " + 
                              str(vulgarFraction))

    if vulgarFraction[len(vulgarFraction)-1].isdigit():
        return float(vulgarFraction)
    else:
        return float(vulgarFraction[:len(vulgarFraction)-1]) + unicodedata.numeric(vulgarFraction[len(vulgarFraction)-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly what asked, perhaps someone wants it converted to a fraction rather than to a float.  After all, a fraction is what it really represents.

`unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", "⅕")` results in `"1⁄5"`.  This is not (presently) understood by `fractions.Fraction`, which expects a fraction described with `/` rather than `⁄`.  However, that is easy to replace:

```
In [313]: def unifrac_to_frac(s):
     ...:     return fractions.Fraction(unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", s).replace("⁄", "/"))
     ...: 

In [315]: unifrac_to_frac("⅕")
Out[315]: Fraction(1, 5)

In [316]: unifrac_to_frac("½")
Out[316]: Fraction(1, 2)

In [317]: unifrac_to_frac("↉")
Out[317]: Fraction(0, 1)
```