# Convert string into floating point in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to convert a string into floating point in Python: 
I have the following Unicode string which I want to convert to 0.02 floating point:

```
t = (data["streams"][0]["time_base"]) 
print t
```

And this is the output `u'1/50'`

I am writing a program which is extracting information from a JSON file and in the future I will need to convert similar strings and I want to automate the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert unicode characters to floats in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263796/how-do-i-convert-unicode-characters-to-floats-in-python)

Comment: what can be your unicode strings? apart from 1/50 I mean. Are those always fractions? something else?

Comment: @Svekke when I try your method I got an error: TypeError: need a single Unicode character as parameter

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there are always fractions, actually this is the framerate represented as a fraction so it is always 1/24, 1/25, 1/59.94, 1/60 and so on.

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov: And if you use `float(u'1/50')` ?

Comment: @Svekke I got an error: "ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1/50"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split at `/`, convert to floats, and divide the numbers:

```
>>> num1, num2 = [float(x) for x in t.split('/')]
>>> num1 / num2
0.02
```