# Replacing Unicode character in pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a problem with a pandas Dataframe that amongst other things contains the number of rooms in an apartment (type String).

This data consists of a unicode character **u"\u00BD"** (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bd/index.htm).

How do i effectively replace this character with decimal values so that instead of the unicode character the data will read `2.5, 3.5, 4.5 etc (Still String format)`.

**It currently looks like this:** `2½, 3½, 4½ etc` And i want the values in the column to be `2.5, 3.5, 4.5 etc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert unicode characters to floats in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263796/how-do-i-convert-unicode-characters-to-floats-in-python)

Comment: If Udi's code had not worked I could have tried this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your column with:

```
df['rooms'] = df['rooms'].str.replace("½", ".5")
```

To make it a float:

```
df['rooms'] = df['rooms'].str.replace("½", ".5").apply(float)
```